# PHP 301 redirect - over 3,000 dynamic URL's

Tags: php, dynamic, http-status-code-301

There's over 3,000 URL's I have to `301 redirect`. I accidently duplicated the use of the city / state in a lot of URL's which makes them repetitive and too long. I can programatically generate over 3,000 `if statements` for the URL's that needs to be `301 redirected`. But, This will be thousands of line of code at the top of every page. Here's 3 example `redirects` from the 3,000+ URL's using this approach.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city-alabama') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/colleges/central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city");
    exit;
    }

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'athens-state-university-athens-alabama') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/colleges/athens-state-university-alabama");
    exit;
    }

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'auburn-university-auburn-alabama') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/colleges/auburn-university-alabama");
    exit;
    }
```

This method is effective, but I worry that it's bad practice. There's another approach where you use an associative array instead.  It's like this:

```
$redirects = array('central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city-alabama' => 'central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city','athens-state-university-athens-alabama' => 'athens-state-university-alabama','auburn-university-auburn-alabama' => 'auburn-university-alabama');

if(array_key_exists($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $redirects)) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/colleges/$redirects[1]");
    exit;
    }
```

I could have that slightly wrong, but you can see what it's supposed to do. What's the best way to approach this? I don't think I can effectively use `.htaccess` because of how unique each redirect is. There's no consistent variable for each URL. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an associative array, but you can use linebreaks to keep it legible, like so:

```
$redirects = array(
    'central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city-alabama' => 'central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city',
    'athens-state-university-athens-alabama' => 'athens-state-university-alabama',
    'auburn-university-auburn-alabama' => 'auburn-university-alabama',
    'etc...', 'etc...'
);
```

Another alternative is to store this in a database and look it up that way, that way you don't need to maintain the PHP file itself which might be locked-down for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks Daj. Would you know if this acceptable practice from an SEO perspective? I'm worried that doing this for over 3000 URL's is frowned upon by Google / the SERPS.

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable provided that these redirects are permanent (as the 301 suggests) and you're redirecting users to canonical addresses.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean having something like this in the <head> of each page? *** <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.website.com/colleges/central-alabama-community-college-alexander-city" />

Comment: No, but that doesn't hurt either :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should place your redirects in a db,

Then use .htaccess to redirect to a single php script that does a 301 redirect to the correct URL.

Comment: Can you give an example of the .htaccess code?  I'm also a little confused on what to store in the db.  I have the old / new URL stored with each row of data.  Is that what I'd want?  Can you provide a more detailed answer on how to do this solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting this in your `.htaccess` file will be the best solution. It can be implemented quite easily. I also feel this is a much better solution than putting all of the logic into your PHP file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://www.mysite.com/new-page.html
```

Comment: That isn't really an option because has over 3000 URIs to redirect.

Comment: @Dai it's one line per redirect, just like your solution. I'd rather keep my 301's in .htaccess than PHP.

Comment: My concern is that Mod_Rewrite doesn't store redirects in an associative array, but a slow regex store. Whereas with the PHP associative array you know it's always going to be fast.